# Can't Power Down - Disabling IRQ #16

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, restart

Can't power down after installing Ubuntu 16.04. with the command line "shutdown", using the shutdown button or restart option. The last line usually reads:

*Disabling IRQ #16*

Could you please help by suggesting logs I could post here.

[image]

--- edit logs added ---

Output **cat /proc/interrupts**
 - thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:         44          0          0          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  1:          1          0          0          1   IO-APIC   1-edge      i8042
  7:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   7-edge      parport0
  8:          0          0          1          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:          1          1          1          0   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          1          1          1          1   IO-APIC  12-edge      i8042
 16:         28      11115      40899      12677   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 23:        149       7756     322565       8480   IO-APIC  23-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
 24:         73     108320     304291     122152   PCI-MSI 1048576-edge      xhci_hcd
 25:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 1048577-edge      xhci_hcd
 26:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 1048578-edge      xhci_hcd
 27:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 1048579-edge      xhci_hcd
 28:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 1048580-edge      xhci_hcd
 29:         15         12     321857         13   PCI-MSI 524288-edge      enp1s0
 30:       4034     111846       4048       4034   PCI-MSI 512000-edge      0000:00:1f.2
 31:        143        133        136     111787   PCI-MSI 32768-edge      i915
 32:          4         10          8          3   PCI-MSI 360448-edge      mei_me
 33:        300        298        297        307   PCI-MSI 442368-edge      snd_hda_intel
NMI:       1782       1536       1404       1226   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:    7352236    1758703    3176620    1063809   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:       1782       1536       1404       1226   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          2          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          2          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:     782492     149196     235116     119987   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:       2205       1924       1457       2107   Function call interrupts
TLB:     510335     474369     440071     476506   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
DFR:          0          0          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:         98         98         98         98   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
PIN:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
```

Output **dmidecode**

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: V17.1
    Release Date: 09/02/2010
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 2048 kB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        ESCD support is available
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        LS-120 boot is supported
        ATAPI Zip drive boot is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
    BIOS Revision: 8.15
```

Further details:
Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz × 4
64-bit ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output from `cat /proc/interrupts`

Comment: did, thank you @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: Check your BIOS setting and if you have options for `XHCI` set it to `Enabled` as per: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192821

Comment: Oh no, it doesn't. Added dmidecode to the logs.

Comment: Can you try to disable legacy Usb in Bios.

Comment: @kukulo ok, disabled legacy usb but it still read `Disabling IRQ #16` in the last line and hung up.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix could you please tell me if you see any XHCI related options? ... I've posted all the bios screens here http://imgur.com/a/ZFTqL

Comment: I don't use that bios but try USB controller, USB legacy and wake. Change them and see...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the command **sudo reboot** or **sudo shutdown**. If none of these items work, type **sudo halt** and when everything is halted, press and hold the power button on your computer, this usually works for me. **sudo reboot** just restarts your computer, **sudo halt** stops all of your programs and then enables you to power down your computer manually. Make sure you use sudo, sudo also known as SUPER USER DO tells your pc what to do and that the command comes from the SUPER USER.

Comment: Thank you. Neither reboot, shutdown nor halt work. The system hangs on every one.